# FitText and FastClick wont work on jQuery Mobile multi page layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

My problem is that I am using FitText and FastClick jQuery plugins and both work fine when I have everything on multi `.html` sheets. But when I set them up in jQuery Mobile's multi page template, where everything is all in one HTML file, the plugins do not work after page 2. All other JS and CSS work fine, just not those 2 plugins; although re-sizing the window will make FitText work. It is like it's just not reading the window size at first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery mobile's built in 'vclick' [300ms delay committing feature](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html). By using this you can omit using FastClick. Because fastclick does the same thing by removing the 300ms delay. You are not having any problem with Jquery mobile and FitText. So you won't experience any problem using 'vclick' and FitText together. You won't have to face lot of troubles. Here is an example.

```
$("#element").bind('vclick', function(event) {
   decrementInput(this.id);event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, this could do the trick for fitText:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function () {
    $("h1").fitText(0.273);
    $(".download").fitText(1);
    /* or put whatever you want to fit in here */
});
```

Working jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5TDg9/J5gKj/).

Answer (score 0):

Scripts and styles referenced in the head of a page won't have any effect when a page is loaded via Ajax which is the case for Multipage Page templates, but they will execute if the page is requested normally via HTTP.

When scripting jQuery Mobile sites, both scenarios need to be considered. The reason that the head of a page is ignored when requested via Ajax is that the potential of re-executing the same JavaScript is very high (it's common to reference the same scripts in every page of a site).

Due to the complexity of attempting to work around that issue, the task of executing page-specific scripts is left to the individual, and assume head scripts are only expected to execute once per browsing session.

The Workaround is to Call the plugging every time the page shows. Its worth Noting that a new ID or class must be given when the plugging is called on every page. ie $('#FittetxtA'). for page one, $('#FittetxtB') for page two and so on. The method below is what i use for a zoom plugging and works as expected. Without the 'pageshow' functions for each page i am unable to zoom on any page but just on page one.

Example

```
<script>
            $( '#page1' ).on( 'pageshow',function(event){

             /// call to pluggings /// 

             $("#Fit_a").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '40px' });

             FastClick.attach(document.body);

            });

             $( '#page2' ).on( 'pageshow',function(event){

             /// call to pluggings ///

             $("#Fit_b").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '40px' });

             FastClick.attach(document.body);

            });

             $( '#page3' ).on( 'pageshow',function(event){

             /// call to plugging ///

            $("#Fit_c").fitText(1.2, { minFontSize: '20px', maxFontSize: '40px' });

            FastClick.attach(document.body);

            });

             /// etc ///
        </script>
```

I'm not 100% sure that this is the best way to call Fast click as i didn't see that many different examples on calling this plugging when i checked the Github pages